# Invalid JSON file error while importing JSON in Firebase

Tags: json, firebase

I'm trying to import a json file (titled, 'filename.json') into my firebase database using 'Import JSON' under 'Database.'

However, i am getting an Invalid JSON file error.

The foll is the structure of my JSON that i wish to import. Can you pls help me with where i am going wrong with this:

```
    {
        "checklist": "XXX",
        "notes": ""
    }
    { "checklist": "XXX",
        "notes": ""
    }       
    {
        "checklist": "XXX",
        "notes": ""
    }
    {
        "checklist": "XXX",
        "notes": ""
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Your objects need commas between them. Basically, any line where you've got an `}` here (except for the last one), throw a comma after it. Then wrap the whole thing in a `[]` so it's a valid json array.

Comment: ah.. all righty, that works, thanks. but i'm not getting the firebase keys (alphanumeric code) with each object... each object is simply associated with a number... how can i import my JSON so that each object gets its own firebase key.

Comment: @Nosail "how can i import my JSON so that each object gets its own firebase key." Did you ever figure this out?